# Autorest C# client generation not respecting input/output types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, autorest

I'm trying to generate a C# API client for my .NET 6 Web API project using [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/AutoRest), but my generated client doesn't seem to care about my request and response data types.

My controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CalculateController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost(Name = "Add")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AddResponseData), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public AddResponseData Add([FromBody] AddRequestData data)
    {
        return new()
        {
            Sum = data.Value1 + data.Value2
        };
    }
}
```

Models:

```cs
public class AddRequestData
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class AddResponseData
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```

I generate the client using a PowerShell script:

```
$solutionName = "AutorestTest"
$apiProject = "AutorestTest.Api"
$clientProject = "AutorestTest.Client"

# Build solution
dotnet build $solutionName.sln

# Generate swagger.json
Set-Location $apiProject
dotnet swagger tofile --output "../swagger.json" "bin/Debug/net6.0/$apiProject.dll" v1
Set-Location ..

# Generate client files
autorest `
    --input-file="swagger.json" `
    --output-folder="$clientProject/Generated" `
    --clear-output-folder `
    --namespace="$clientProject" `
    --csharp
```

I expect to be able to use the generated client like this:

```cs
var client = new AutorestTestApiClient(new ("https://localhost:7164"), new());
// or just `AddResponseData result = ...`
Result<AddResponseData> result = await client.AddAsync(new AddRequestData()
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2
});
Debug.Assert(result.Value.Sum == 3);
```

But the generated `AddAsync` method looks like this:

```cs
public virtual async Task<Response> AddAsync(RequestContent content, ContentType contentType, RequestContext context = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

It uses these generic `RequestContent` and `Response` types, instead of my own data types.

How do I make autorest generate clients that use `AddRequestData` and `AddResponseData` models in the generated methods?

Here's my full sample project: [GitHub Rene-Sackers/AutorestTest](https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/AutorestTest)

Comment: having the same problem, any solutions yet?

Comment: @conterio unfortunately, no. We switched to NSwag to generate our clients. We generate the swagger file as we did, (`dotnet swagger tofile`), then I have 2 extra projects, a `ClientGenerator` and a `Client` project. The generator project is a CLI app and uses the `NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp` NuGet package and runs `new CSharpClientGenerator(document, settings).GenerateFile()` and outputs into the `Client` project. Then we build and package the client project. Example project: https://github.com/Rene-Sackers/NswagExample